# Itunes connect/apple app store revenue

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I am planning to sell an app to the apple app store(iOS). Is it possible to tell itunes connect to split the revenue between 3 other people in different ratios?(I am registered as an individual)

OR should I put into my bank account and then distribute it(But this will cause tax issues right? - anyone overcome this?)

Thanks,

Comment: This question doesn't belong to SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to have the payments sent to your bank account and distributed from there.

The tax issues will depend on where you live.  If your country collects income tax then you will have to declare the earnings and pay tax as per your countries rules.  Apple does not sort this kind of tax for you, unlike a regular job.  All they sort is sales tax.